# How to remove a directory role member in MS Graph PowerShell module?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I've been looking for a way to remove a directory role member from Azure using the [MS Graph PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0), however, I can't seem to find any cmdlet to do this.

I'm currently using the [New-MgDirectoryRoleMemberByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/new-mgdirectoryrolememberbyref?view=graph-powershell-1.0) cmdlet in order to add users to directory roles (such as Global Administrator) on the tenants we look after, however I can't seem to find a way to subsequently remove them.

I can see from [this article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-delete-member?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that the MS Graph API exposes the delete functionality, but it doesn't detail a PowerShell cmdlet capable of performing this action.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to remove a user from a role using the MS Graph PowerShell SDK please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there's not currently a PowerShell cmdlet for this. The [migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0#directory-roles) lists that the equivalent to `Remove-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember` is `Remove-MgDirectoryRoleScopedMember`, but this seems to be incorrect as this cmdlet is for roles that are scoped to administrative units.

In the meantime you could still use the Azure AD PowerShell cmdlet or the Graph API.

**Using Graph API with PowerShell**

You'll need an access token, which is typically obtained using a client application (App Registration). This access token is required in the request headers.

A more manual method that can be used for testing purposes is to open [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), sign-in, and click on the **Access token** button.

[image]

The client application (or the Graph Explorer user) will also need the permission `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` (as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-delete-member?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions))

```
# Example request

$roleId = ""
$roleTemplateId = ""
$userId = ""    
$accessToken = ""

# Use this endpoint when using the role Id
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/$roleId/members/$userId/`$ref"

# Use this endpoint when using the role template ID
# $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=$roleTemplateId/members/$userId/`$ref"

# Splatted parameters for the HTTP request    
$params = @{
    Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" }
    Method  = "Delete"
    Uri     = $uri
}

Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

**Using Graph Explorer**

Make a request using the `DELETE` method to whichever endpoint

```
DELETE /directoryRoles/{role-id}/members/{id}/$ref
DELETE /directoryRoles/roleTemplateId={roleTemplateId}/members/{id}/$ref
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I couldn't see any cmdlet for it then. Is there a way to execute arbitrary graph api requests using the MS Graph module as I guess this would be a way around it?

Comment: @NiMux If you mean is there a way to make a MS Graph API request using PowerShell, yes, but you need to understand how to configure a client app and permissions. Updated answer

Comment: @scottwtang, what bout using the new cmdlet Remove-MgGroupMemberByRef https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/remove-mggroupmemberbyref?view=graph-powershell-1.0&preserve-view=true ?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer You might have referenced the wrong cmdlet in your comment? I can confirm that the cmdlet `Remove-MgDirectoryRoleMemberByRef` can now be used to remove a role from a user

Comment: Hi @scottwtang, yes, that is the correct command., but how do I get -DirectoryObjectId <String> and -DirectoryRoleId <String> value from ? There are so many Get-MgDirectoryRole* cmdlets.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer My previous comment was 6 months ago. Trying today, I can't get this to work using either Graph Explorer or the `Remove-MgDirectoryRoleMemberByRef` cmdlet, so something might have changed. `DirectoryObjectId` would be just the target user's object ID, and you can use `Get-MgDirectoryRole` to get the `DirectoryRoleId`